# Typescript import from root path not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, tsconfig

In my `tsconfig.json` I have set outDir to `lib`, and baseURL to `./src`.
(This is in my typescript firebase functions project)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "lib",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"]
    },
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Folder Struccture

```
    src
    ├── tsconfig.json
    ├── lib
    │   ├── test.js
    │
    │── test.ts
    │── data
    │   ├── names.json
```

Import Code (test.ts)

```
    import names from "~/data/names.json";
```

But when it compiles, it uses the folder `lib` as a root path in imports, hence says `Module not found`

The error

```
    !!  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: 
    Error: Cannot find module '~/data/names.json'
    Require stack:
    - C:\Proj\src\lib\test.js
```

How can the referencing be fixed in tsconfig or other way?

Answer (score 0):

Move tsconfig.json out of the src folder, and change the outDir field with:

```
"outDir": "src/lib",
```

Comment: It's already outside of the src folder.

Comment: Okay, try changing the field in `path` to `"~/*":["."]`